# Stripping Hyphens from Numbers in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and I need help removing hyphens from an Excel document. I usually use python, and could just use .strip, I was wondering if there is an equivalent in Excel. The cell I will be stripping the hyphens from is static, so the cell it self could be hardcoded I think.

I am trying to go from

233-79-01 to 2337901.

I tried these following lines of code

```
  Sub striphyphen()

  A5 = replace(A4,'-','')

  End Sub
```

I am getting a compiling error, and am not sure why.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `Range("A5").Value = Replace(Range("A4").Value, "-", "")`. Or enclose `A5` and `A4` in brackets. Fix the single quotes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` as said [@BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) and [@JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)

```
Sub Test()
Dim myString as String
Dim newString as String

myString = "233-79-01"

newString = replace(myString, "-", "")

MsgBox newString

End Sub
```

**Note** That you can also set `mystring = Cells(4,1).Value` or `mystring = Range("A4").Value`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are wrongly referencing cells. The way you do it is the way to reference variables (just like in any other language).

To reference cell you can use one of the following (A4 cell for example):

```
Cells(4, 1) ' Cells(row, column)
Range("A4")
[A4]
```